# Why same notification is pushed many times to android and iphone devices

Tags: java, android, ios, google-cloud-messaging, javapns

I have used javapns for pushing notifications to ios and android.gcm.server to push notification for android devices. But when I sent one notifications to many devices each device get multiple number of copies of the notification sent. Sometimes this number is 2 and sometimes 3. Hardly it delivers only one which I expect always. Any Ideas ?

My code is as below

```
public void pushNotificationsToAndroid(String pushMessage,
            String contentType, String content, String notification_id,
            List<String> devices) {



        try {

            Sender sender = new Sender(
                    properties
                            .getProperty("notification.android.senderIdDemo"));
            com.google.android.gcm.server.Message message = new com.google.android.gcm.server.Message.Builder()
                    .collapseKey("1").timeToLive(3).delayWhileIdle(true)
                    .addData("message", pushMessage)
                    .addData("content_type", contentType)
                    .addData("content", content)
                    .addData("notification_id", notification_id).build();

            MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devices, 1);

            if (result.getResults() == null) {

                System.out.println(result.getFailure());
                logger.debug("getFailure() of sender.send() method :",
                        result.getFailure());

            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("erorr push notification ");

        }

        System.out.println("sent not at " + new Date());
        logger.debug(
                "exit pushNotificationsToAndroid() method : current time is ",
                new Date());

    }

    public void pushNotificationsToIOS(String pushMessage, String contentType,
            String content, String notification_id, List<String> devices)
             {


        boolean production = true;
        String password = properties
                .getProperty("notification.ios.password");

        String keyStroke = properties
                .getProperty("notification.ios.certFileName");

        AppleNotificationServer jksServer = null;


        try {

            jksServer = new AppleNotificationServerBasicImpl(keyStroke,
                    password, ConnectionToAppleServer.KEYSTORE_TYPE_JKS,
                    production);

        } catch (KeystoreException keystoreException) {

            logger.error("erorr creating jksServer");

        }

        PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.complex();

        try {

            payload.addAlert(pushMessage);

        } catch (JSONException e2) {

            logger.error("erorr creating payload alert");

        }

        try {

            payload.addCustomDictionary("content_type", contentType);

        } catch (JSONException e1) {

            logger.error("erorr creating payload content_type");

        }

        try {

            payload.addCustomDictionary("content", content);

        } catch (JSONException e1) {

            logger.error("erorr creating payload content");

        }

        try {

            payload.addCustomDictionary("notification_id", notification_id);

        } catch (JSONException e1) {

            logger.error("erorr creating payload notification_id");

        }

        PushNotificationManager pushManager = new PushNotificationManager();

        try {

            pushManager.initializeConnection(jksServer);

        } catch (CommunicationException | KeystoreException e) {

            logger.error("erorr connecting Server");


        }
        try {

            List<PushedNotification> notifications = pushManager
                    .sendNotifications(payload, Devices.asDevices(devices));


        } catch (CommunicationException | KeystoreException e) {

            logger.error("erorr push notifications");

        }

    }
```

Comment: post your code ...!!!!!

Comment: Problem should be in your server side code...

Comment: @GauravPandey  I posted the code

Answer (score 1):

In [android official site](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#canonical) says about some reasons for duplicate message conditions .

Comment: yes I saw that. But my case issue was a thread related one and I fixed that. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Can you tell me clearly about your problem.Because i am also facing same problem.